# Is there anywhere in Doha to see modern Arabic/Islamic art?

Tags: museums, qatar, doha, artworks

Yesterday, I spent a very enjoyable and informative time at the [Museum of Islamic Art](http://www.mia.org.qa/en/) in Doha, including seeing how the various styles of artwork developed over the centuries.

After that, I'm interested to see how modern Arabic and Islamic artists are taking those things forward.

Is there somewhere in the centre of Doha where I can see such modern art? It needn't have a building quite as impressive as the MIA has (photo below), but given how hard it is to find a taxi in Doha, something nearby would be great!

[image: Museum of Islamic Art]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is!

The [Arab Museum of Modern Art (MATHAF)](http://www.mathaf.org.qa/en/) holds a fair sized permanent collection of Arabic and Islamic modern and contemporary art works, along with changing special exhibitions. Permanent exhibits are free, as are seeing the sculptures outside, while special exhibitions are fairly cheap.

The museum is located east of the city centre, at Education City. That would normally make it a bit of faff to get to... Except... There's a free shuttle bus!

The bus (a bright pink minibus) runs between the Museum of Islamic Art on the Corniche and MATHAF every hour Wednesday to Sunday, [timings on the MATHAF website](http://www.mathaf.org.qa/en/). It's supposed to take about 30 minutes, but often takes closer to 45 in traffic.

There's some very interesting and good stuff at MATHAF, it's worth the bus ride out from the city centre!

(Supposedly nearby is also the [gallery at VCU Qatar (Virginia Commonwealth University in Qatar)](http://www.qatar.vcu.edu/events). However, because of ongoing works for the Education City tram, you'll face a ~30 minute unsignposted walk through what's basically a building site to get there, and the same back, assuming a passing expat doesn't take pity and offer you a lift. Until the tarms are done, I'd say it's best to skip the small VCUQatar gallery, as it isn't an easy or fun walk)